# Disable JavaScript for Current Page

Tags: javascript, php

I'm building a debug script that is to be included at the top of my `index.php`

I would like to provide a checkbox that when checked, disables all javascript, jquery etc on the page.

I'm saving these settings with `$_SESSION`

I've already found a soloution that replaces all `<script></script>` tags with `<!--<script></script>-->`. But would like to know if there is anthing cleaner, more specific.

Since the file is included at the top of my index, could I write something in javascript to unbind any events/listeners/triggers etc?

I would prefer not to change any of my javascript, as the idea is to include this at the top of each project/build as a standalone piece.
Thanks!

Comment: This is not an answer, but you could also look for browser extensions that can block javascript.

Comment: Please check this link:-http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?99591-How-to-disable-JavaScript-on-any-page

Comment: thanks camil, I have already got something of the sort. Would love to have a checkbox at the top of the page i could toggle it with. Not always in one browser/location.

Comment: If you only want to disable JS while debugging you could purposely throw a js exception? that would prevent anything else from getting executed.

Comment: that sounds great @SheldonNeilson would you care to leave an answer/example?

Comment: @SheldonNeilson: What kind of exception do you plan on throwing to make a whole page malfunction?

Comment: Unfortunately that was a silly idea.. it would only prevent execution of scripts in the same scope. E.g. the same <script> tag etc.. There probably isn't an easy solution.

Comment: ok thanks @SheldonNeilson , I have provided some more clarity in the answer below. Is there no easy way to achieve this? Not sure why I got downvoted either :(

Comment: Nevermind "easy", there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't disable JavaScript with JavaScript.

Simply put, you can't make sure your JS is the first to execute, nor can you reliably disable scripts all over the page.

Imagine how that would mess with normal browsing... Some malicious site disables JS on your browser, and you're gonna have to figure out where the setting is.

I'm sure that you can dream about resetting it, after an hour or 2 of browsing.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I can understand if the requirement was to disable the users javascript indefinatly. However, I would just like to disable it for a single page load/session. I was wondering if I could get javascript to throw an error and stop parsing the rest of the page. Its just to allow me to disable it with a checkbox, in page.

Comment: By the time the user can interact with the checkbox, that page's JS would already have been executed. If you have access to a page like that, why not include some kind of boolean GET parameter to just exclude script files? Also, how do you plan on turning JS back on?

Comment: I'm planning on setting a `session` var with `disableJavascript=true`. This is in the head, and would then listen and if set, append either a var to the script tag

Comment: For the reason of portability, I would prefer not to have to mess with any source files. I was planning on storing the value in a session, then if met either thorw some JS exception to break it, or search for script tags and comment out.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what you want to do simply can't be done reliably. You can't make sure your JS is the first to execute, nor can you reliably disable scripts all over the page.

Comment: thanks for the honest answer. If you want to alter yours to include this I will happily mark as correct. Not sure why ive been downvoted for this too! :(